# How would you get a command to run on startup as a non-root user, on BeagleBone Black?

Tags: linux, clojure, boot, beagleboneblack

I have generally speaking followed the instructions [here](http://www.nunoalves.com/open_source/?p=308), and tried using `su - <myuser> -c "the command"` within the service script there. However, I'm trying to run a Clojure application via Leiningen, and it seems that neither `lein` can't be found by the process. I can use something like `su - <myuser> -c "/path/to/lein run ..."`, but then I get an error that `java` isn't found.

How do I get this command to run such that it has access to my environment?

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be quite simple. I did

```
su - <myuser> -c "source ~/.bashrc; cd ~/chicken-coop; ~/bin/lein run"`
```

The key is to `source ~/.bashrc;`, which adds the normal things to your path, so lein knows where `java` is.

Comment: if you see issues with startup time or memory usage, you may want to consider running `lein uberjar` when you update the code, and `java -jar [your-project.jar]` to run. Otherwise, `lein trampoline run` can be used to reduce resource usage slightly.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I actually have been using `trampoline`, but left that out of the answer since it didn't have any bearing on the solution. I'll consider doing `ubarjar` though if startup time becomes an issue (it isn't at the moment for what I'm working on).